# programmatically creating classes undefined

Tags: javascript

I am following a book on Javascript and the example doesn't seem to return any value. I don't have much experience with OOP though.

I believe this is a programmatical way to create classes, but it returns undefined any way

[image: JS console on chrome]

What do you make of this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: _declaration_ statements (`var`, `let`, `const`, `function` and `class` statements) create what the ECMAScript specification refers to as an "empty normal completion". At the language level, that looks like an `undefined`.

Comment: If you just call the variable you assigned the class instantiation to, it'll evaluate properly. of course console.log doesn't have a return value, it's only function is to trigger a printing side effect in the console. When you console log it, you can see it printed in the console, which means it's defined and as that value... printed in the console.... you can see it there

Comment: Thank you guys for clear explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected, variable declarations always return undefined. 
E.g., `let a = 0`, `var b = 0`, `const c = 0`.

This doesn't mean `a`, `b`, and `c` are undefined though.

Likewise for your example, `createClass` and `Book` aren't undefined, as seen by your `console.log`.

Comment: So what should I set in constructor ...values spread rest operator to print "Book1" ?